# How to speed up PostgreSQL jsonb datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table has two columns, an `id` and a `jsonb` column. There are about 2500 rows. In the Jsonb column, there are about 17,000 attributes not nested. It is only a single level hierarchy. When searching for an int value on one of the attributes it takes about 5 seconds.

Then I removed most of the attributes from the documents and it was much faster. MongoDB does not have this problem. Is there a way to speed this up?

This reason I choose postgresql is because I need transactions.

Comment: Do some research on GIN indexes (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).  They may help you solve your performance problem.

Comment: "plain" `json` is said to be faster than `jsonb`: http://adpgtech.blogspot.de/2015/09/when-to-use-json-and-when-to-use-jsonb.html And please read: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions then edit your question and add the missing information

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name said - edit the question to add `explain (buffers, analyze)`, and edit question when done. Add other relevant info from that link too.